# How can I draw an implicit function f(x,y,z)=0 with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw the following implicit function with gnuplot

```
x**2+y**2+(z-1)**3-2
```

[image]

I know that maple or matlab can to this very simple but I want to use gnuplot.

Up to know I have no idea so I can't provide a starting point.

<sub>sorry</sub>

Here the result plotted with maple

[image]

Comment: [This](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/implicit/solve-e.html) link might be a good place to start.

Comment: @MarvinPinto: I know this page. I was able to draw different functions with this guidance. Whatever I am not able to adapt this for my function.

Comment: The link in @MarvinPinto's comment seems to be broken. There is a (perhaps well-known) trick to plot implicit functions of two variables, by asking gnuplot  to plot the surface $z = f(x, y)$ and just show the contour $z=0$ - see e.g. [here](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/assume-three-is-equation-fxygxy-and-we.html) - but it won't work for an implicit function of three variables.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Gnuplot FAQ](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00057000000000000000), this is not directly possible. There is a workaround for 2D-functions, but I don't see how this method can be applied to 3D graphs. I'd recommend solving the equation in Octave or some similar program and outputting the solutions to a file, which you can then feed into GnuPlot.